# Not able to publish website on Windows Azure using publish through VS2010

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I am facing this problem when I try to publish my web application on Windows Azure via Visual Studio 2010. I am trying by right click on project and select publish and importing publish profile downloaded from Windows Azure platform.

I am getting this error:

> Error 1 Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("waws-prod-am2-001.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)  0 0 MeraSungard

Comment: Is the instance fully set-up and up and running?

Comment: Yes, I can check that the default website on Windows Azure is up and running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are trying to publish your web application from VS2010 to Windows Azure Websites, the publish process connect to Windows Azure Websites on specific port which is enabled for Web Deploy service. In VS 2010 if the connection to this service port is failed then VS return error as "Web Deploy is installed........ on remote server. The fact is that the WebDeploy service is already running and other machines could connect to the same server and deploy the problem is specific to your network and your machine.

There are two main place to look for 1) your deployment machine firewall 2) Proxy server if you are behind proxy. Try to change the network related settings locally so you can get it working.

Comment: Thanks! I try same process from other machine in other network and it worked. It must be something with network firewall or my machine is vehind proxy server.

Comment: In my case there was no space on the machine, so from Azure Portal > Advance tool > Kudu > Console > CMD > deleted some unncessary files and then it worked..

Answer (score 81):

For those that the answer didn't work for (like me). Alternatively you can set an app setting in your Azure Website:

1. Set **WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM = false** in Azure Management Portal settings (under Website → Configuration → Application Settings). Make sure `false` is in the value field.
2. Download the publish settings again in VS or whatever you use to deploy.
3. Deploy successfully.

*Taken from:*

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efa56eb2-a8b2-4690-92d0-33d97946ed29/cant-deploy-could-not-connect-to-the-remote-computer-xxxscmazurewebsitesnet-using-the?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: In my case there was no space on the machine, so from Azure Portal > Advance tool > Kudu > Console > CMD > deleted some unncessary files and then it worked..

Answer (score 16):

Resetting your "publish profile" also works :)
You can reset it from the Azure Portal at your web app.
[image]

Comment: This is the easiest WORKING solution. This worked for me as well

Comment: First step i was check on WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM but default value is FALSE. So i have tried this solution and it worked. Thanks

Comment: In my case there was no space on the machine, so from Azure Portal > Advance tool > Kudu > Console > CMD > deleted some unncessary files and then it worked..

Answer (score 5):

try to run Visual Studio as admin. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have a web debugging proxy running which logs all HTTP(s) traffic between your computer and the Internet.  My issue was that Fiddler was running because I was debugging a Web API.  I was able to publish successfully after closing Fiddler.

Answer (score 2):

For me publishing start working after network reconnect.

Answer (score 2):

I want to share my solution with the same problem. Also 
`MsDepSvc (Web Deployment Agent Service)` and `WMSvc (Web Management Service)` were running on the remote VM and Visual Studio 2015 still returns an error.

I go to `Azure portal` > `All Resources` >  Find my `Network Security Group` and click on it. > **`Inbound security rules`** and add new rule:

**Name**: your choice. 
**Source**: *Any*. 
**Service**: *Custom* 
**Protocol**: *Any* 
**Port range**: ***8172*** 
**Action** : *Allow*

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when trying to deploy to Azure from VS2013 update 5. It happens intermittently. Sometimes publishing works, sometimes it doesn't.
In my case it turned out to be network related. We use a load balancing router with two WANs connected to it. If the external IP address changes during the deployment process, because the router switched WANs, it fails.
Hope that will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, slightly different solution. I restrict access to the website using the IP.  This is done from app services->Networking->Configure Access Restrictions.

My fix was to add the IP to both tabs, the website tab and the scm tab.

Answer (score 0):

I do not save the password in my publish profile. Even after checking and double checking the password from the portal and entering it when prompted, the publish failed. I knew the problem had something to do with the password because I could enter any bogus password and still get the same exact publish failed error.

What I did was click "Configure" on the publish tab of my project and click on "Validate Connection" on the "Connection" tab after entering the credentials again.

It was able to validate successfully and all subsequent publishes have been successful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, restarting web deploy with complete setup option solved my issue. make sure you have management services started in background from IIS management tool.

Answer (score -2):

Disabling my VPN resolved the issue for me.