# Azure mobile service: publish throwing error VS 2013

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to create azure mobile service from VS 2013, 2 issues I am facing.

1. Host in cloud option is disabled.
2. Getting error on click of Validate connection while publishing the project. error thrown there is "Destination is unreachable".

Log I have extracted from output window is :

> Error ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE: Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("****.scm.azure-mobile.net"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)

I have attached screenshot you reference. Please check.

[image: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/510584]

gone through similar question : [Not able to publish website on Windows Azure using publish through VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471678/not-able-to-publish-website-on-windows-azure-using-publish-through-vs2010?rq=1)

didnt helped though.

Can anyone help me to resolve these issues..? Appreciate the help.

Regards

Ravi Bhat

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this error as well. 
I tried changed two things and it works, yet now I don't remember which one is the root cause:

1. use https instead of http for the server address and destination URL
2. My company has proxy settings for all internet access, I change to the other WIFI without any proxy. So check your internet connection.

You could try this, but I'm not sure if it works.